# Polyfill for IE background-blend-mode multiply

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

Is there a polyfill / method to make "background-blend-mode: multiply" work on IE browsers?

I found this CodePen: http://codepen.io/brav0/pen/bJDxt but it's not working.

In short what blend does:

with some CSS like this:

```
.blend {
  background-image: url('mountains.jpg');
  background-color: #5ece7f;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

You can create cool filters that look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this polyfill is trying to use

```
context.globalCompositeOperation = 'multiply'
```

and as fas as I know, IE doesn't support this either.

[documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974909(v=vs.85).aspx)

So, it's a pity, but I don't know of any easy way to polyfill blend modes in IE